# Transforming lined data to grouped

Tags: python, python-3.x, database, sas

I have a question about transforming a data

if my data is like the following:

```
Variable A  
130  
130  
130 

Variable B  
56  
57  
58  

Variable C  
1100    
1200  
1300
```

in a text file and I want to transform it into something like:

```
Variable A     Variable B    Variable C  
130            56            1100  
130  57   1200  
130  58  1300
```

What should I do?

Comment: It depends ..  are they separate text files for each variable, or one file separated by blank lines? Look into pandas and the `read_table` function to load data from text files

Comment: It does depend a lot on if these are multiple files or a single file. \

Answer (score 0):

Your data is column centric, and SAS data sets are row centric, so a pivot will be required at some point.

The most generic process would:

- input data into many rows of name:value pairs

  - compute a sequence value (row number) for each pair
- sort the input
- transpose by row.

Presuming all data is numeric, here is an example:

```
* construct a demonstration input data file;
* every data value in this construction is via +1 to allow
* examination of the reshaping;

filename havedata temp;

data _null_;
  file havedata;

  call streaminit(123);

  do varname = 'A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'X', 'Y', 'Z';
    put 'Variable ' varname;
    do _n_ = 1 to 100 + rand('uniform',20);
      value + 1; 
      put value;        
    end;
  end;
run;

* read the demo file;

data want_input;
  infile havedata;

  length rownumber 8 name $32 value 8;
  retain name;

  input @;

  if _infile_ =: 'Variable' then do;                /* detect variable landmark in data file */
    rownumber = 0;
    name = substr(_infile_, length('Variable')+1);  
    delete;
  end;

  rownumber + 1;
  input @1 value;
run;

proc sort data=want_input;
  by rownumber name;
run;

proc transpose data=want_input out=want(drop=_name_ rownumber);
  by rownumber;
  id name;
  var value;
run;
```

Things will more complicated if the data file variable 'blocks' are character or date representations.